# Problem in doing database backup for users

Tags: python, django

I am using `django version 2.0.6` and using `db.sqlite3` for my database.

I want to give a functionality to the user to keep a backup of the model objects they have created and load the data whenever needed.

Any idea anyone how to do it in `django`?

Thank you.

**Update**

I have tried the following in my views:

```
def getcompanyObject(request, pk):
    company_details = get_object_or_404(Company, pk=pk)
    all_objects = list(Group1.objects.filter(user=request.user,company=company_details.pk)) + list(Ledger1.objects.filter(user=request.user,company=company_details.pk))
    data = serializers.serialize('json', all_objects)
    data = json.dumps(json.loads(data), indent=4)
    response = HttpResponse(data , content_type='application/json')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=export.json' 
    return response
```

It works fine as it downloads the backup in a json format for users now I have one problem about

How to load the json files for the user.

I mean to say that User will click on a button and it will automatically load the backup files for the user.

Any idea anyone?

Comment: There is one database for entire application right?

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: so you can take the backup why you need user to take backup of database for what reason?

Comment: User can take a backup of their specific model objects which they have created.Not the whole database

Comment: A simple way would be to serialize objects to json/csv and import them whenever needed. You have to implement django views for this.

Comment: Can you show me how it is done. If possible...I am new to django and have tiny experience in serialization using django.@ShanavasM

Comment: Actually you need think again why you want to do this. Why user will take backup of some part of database and extra overhead of maintaining it rather you can take backup each day. If something goes wrong you can restore and user wont even notice it.

Comment: Actually I am creating an accounting app using django, I want to give this funtionality to the user to maintain their bussiness needs for lost data and entry.